# Automatically generate similar docs

Tags: scripts

I need to generate the document containing items from txt file (for example). 
Txt file:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
```

Can I run script (?) which generate about the following:

> Header #1.
>
> 1. Item 1 (from txt)
> 2. Item 4 (from txt)
>
> ---
>
> Header #2.
>
> 1.Item 2 (from txt)
>
> 2.Item 5 (from txt)
>
> ---
>
> Header #3.
>
> 1.Item 3 (from txt)
>
> 2.Item 6 (from txt)

Is it possible or I should use other language and it will be more easier?

Comment: Your question is very unclear at the moment. What do you mean by "Header" here?  Are you generating a single document as output?  If so, you might want to use the `datatool` package, which can read CSV files.

Comment: Or have a look at Pandoc, but how is this TeX-related?

Comment: "Header" here is arbitrary string. 
Yes, I need a single document.

I have a list of items and I need to generate a document with a specific structure. Document should contains items from the list.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still not clear. How do you choose which line from the file goes in which list? Is it arbitrary? Is there a pattern? Do you search for something?  Do you have control over the text file format? If you do, then formatting the text file as CSV would be simpler, I suspect.

Comment: So, I have the txt file with questions. And I want to generate the file with random questions without repetitions. But the output file should be not only list, I need to numerate the pairs of qustions: Ticket #1. 
1.Question 1.
2. Question 2. 
Ticket #2. 
1. Question 3.
2. Question 4.

Comment: Do you know how to generate random numbers without repetitions?

Comment: This is not the main goal. For example, I can use shuf util in Linux to randomize lines and simply read the text file successively.

Comment: so what is the question really?

Comment: I need automatically generate pdf file containing the items from the other text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option.

**file.txt**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio.
Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. 
Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. 
Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. 
Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. 
Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. 
Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. 
Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. 
Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor.
```

**Main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mtctr}
\newcounter{tmp}
\newread\mt
\openin\mt=file.txt
\loop
\read\mt to \mtt
\unless\ifeof\mt
\stepcounter{mtctr}
\expandafter\xdef\csname question\themtctr\endcsname{\mtt}
\repeat
\closein\mt
\xdef\qustionnbr{\themtctr}
\setcounter{mtctr}{0}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\thetmp.\theenumi.}

\begin{document}
\loop
\stepcounter{tmp}
\section*{Header \thetmp}
\begin{enumerate}
\stepcounter{mtctr}
\item \csname question\themtctr\endcsname
\ifnum\value{mtctr}<\qustionnbr
\stepcounter{mtctr}
\item \csname question\themtctr\endcsname
\fi
\end{enumerate}
\ifnum\value{mtctr}<\qustionnbr
\repeat
\end{document}
```

**Update** Here is a shorter version.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newread\mt
\openin\mt=file.txt

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\thetmp.\theenumi.}

\begin{document}

\loop
\unless\ifeof\mt
\read\mt to \mtt
\ifeof\mt\else
\stepcounter{tmp}
\section*{Header \thetmp}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \mtt
\read\mt to \mtt
\ifeof\mt\else
\item \mtt
\fi
\end{enumerate}
\fi
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: answer updated. a shorter version is add.